# DI with Castle Windsor in Windows Service hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

I am trying to get Castle Windsor DI working with a WCF service hosted as a Windows Service. I have gone with the approach here

[WCF Service Library hosted as a Windows Service using Castle.Windsor 3.0 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064586/wcf-service-library-hosted-as-a-windows-service-using-castle-windsor-3-0-issue)

However the problem I have is that if my service implementation class doesn't have a default parameterless constructor, ServiceHost will not allow me to create an instance of this in OnStart(). If I provide a parameterless constructor, service console starts the service with that constructor and so I don't get any dependencies injected.

Code below

```
public class WindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost ServiceHost;

        public WindowsService()
        {
            ServiceName = "CRMCustomerService";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Bootstrap the Castle Windsor DI setup
            Run(CreateContainer().Resolve<ServiceBase>());
        }

        #region Service methods

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (ServiceHost != null)
            {
                ServiceHost.Close();
            }

            ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CustomerService));
            ServiceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (ServiceHost != null)
            {
                ServiceHost.Close();
                ServiceHost = null;
            }
        }


        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        private static IWindsorContainer CreateContainer()
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
            return container;
        }

        #endregion
    }

[ServiceBehaviorAttribute(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        private readonly IDataRepository _repository;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public CustomerService(IDataRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _logger = new RootLogger(Level.Error);
        }
}

public class ServicesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container
                .AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f =>
                                              {
                                                  f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
                                              })
                .Register(
                    Component
                        .For<IDataRepository>()
                        .ImplementedBy<CustomerRepository>()
                        .LifeStyle.Transient
                        .AsWcfService(),
                    Component.For<ServiceBase>().ImplementedBy<WindowsService>());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I want to bootstrap Windsors DI container on service start up and when an instance of the WCF service is created, for it to inject the dependencies at that point.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should have two constructors as another poster suggested, one
    default and one with your dependencies as parameters.

2) As you see in the post you linked to you should use Castle's WCF Facility to
    host the service (notice the `AsWcfService` syntax in the post you
    linked to).   All you have to do is write the Castle code, register
    all your services dependencies and Castle will take care of the
    rest. It's almost like magic!

Answer (score 0):

You could have two constructors. Where the parameterless one calls the overload that takes the dependency as a parameter.

```
public WindowsService()
    this(new ServiceHost());

public WindowsService(ServiceHost serviceHost)
{ 
    this.ServiceHost = serviceHost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate service implementation with required constructor and pass it to service host as a parameter, e.g.

```
var service = CustomerService(container.Resolve<IDataRepository>());
ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(service);
```

or even like this, if you have configured container correctly:

```
var service = container.Resolve<ICustomerService>();
ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(service);
```

However in this case it would work in singleton mode, and as I remember you need to change ***InstanceContextMode*** of the service implementation to ***Single***.